# Charles can not work when using IOS simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, charles-proxy

I am going to catch tcp packages by using Charles when developing IOS app, but it failed to catch anything when the app running in the simulator.However everything works well when I using safari or other apps both in or out of the simulator.So it seems that only my app in the simulator has this problem.

I have tried this https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/ssl-proxying-with-ios-9/ ,but it didn't work.

Please do me a favor. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well...It seems that Charles is unable to capture tcp package, it is designed to capture http/https traffic instead...

Wireshark may be a good choice BTW.